# How do I see the query string in my webpage from a separate php file?

Tags: php

I'm trying to debug my code (which honestly I'm not very good at and still trying to expand on those skills). **How do I see the query string in my webpage from a separate php file?** I put the query string into a variable and tried to echo the variable on the page but it killed my entire page.

PHP File:

```
 $sqlCheck = "INSERT INTO change_of_address (parcel_id, address_1, address_2, City, State, Zip, Country) VALUES ('" . $parcel_id . "','" . $address1 . "','" . $address2 . "','" . $city . "','" . $state . "','" . $zip . "','" . $country . "')";
```

Webpage:

```
<?php

    require_once('config.php');
    require_once('classes/search.php');
    require_once('classes/add-address.php');

    echo $sqlCheck;

?>
```

The error I am getting is :

```
Warning: require_once(../config.php): failed to open stream: 
         No such file or directory in 
         /var/www/lcv-data-website/classes/add-address.php and ( ! ) 
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../config.php' 
     (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in 
     /var/www/lcv-data-website/classes/add-address.php on line 2
```

Comment: just make sure first that those variables are defined.

Comment: "killed the entire page" HOW? echoing out a variable should never kill a script.

Comment: before `require_once('config.php')` add these lines: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Check now, what happens.

Comment: In which file is the query? What errors appear?

Comment: @lolka_bolka it says Warning: require_once(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/lcv-data-website/classes/add-address.php  and ( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/lcv-data-website/classes/add-address.php on line 2
 which i dont understand because the file is there... :(

Comment: the `include` for an `included` file is not work as you think. where do you `requrire_once('../config.php');` I see `requrire_once('config.php');` without `../`

Comment: in the separate php file i have `require_once('../config.php');`. the separate php file is a call from the jquery ajax that is suppose  to take the information the user enters and insert it into a database. I keep getting unexpected token errors.

Comment: @MarcB I have no idea. I refreshed the page and it was blank. I got it back but still can't figure out what i'm doing wrong with this thing. I keep getting unexpected token errors

Answer (score 1):

First of all `query string` is normally used to describe the values passed on the URL after the `?` character i.e. `example.com/script.php?a=1&b=2&c=3`

Your issue is nothing to do with displaying the value of the variable `$sqlCheck;`.

If you actually read the error message it is saying **I cannot find the file you are trying to include using the** `require_once` **command**

Remember that the `include` and `require` functions expect the path to the file that you are including to be relative to the location of the script that they are located in.

As you statement is `require_once('config.php');` then PHP expects to find it in the same directory as this script.

I would therefore assume that `config.php` **does not exist in the same directory as the script** The second error message is saying that PHP also cannot find this file in any of the directories that you (or someone) have configure the PHP search path to be either.

Change the statement so that the `require_once('config.php');` is correctly path'd

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to show the query as a string on my webpage to see if the variables are being passed into the `INSERT` statement. The config file only sets the connection to the db which is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: Its not irrelevant if the code never gets to the line that displays the query code. Execution never gets to that line as a failed `require_once` terminates execution

Comment: For future reference, **FATAL** error means the code stopped execution at the line number mentioned in the error message.